# uname and Solaris versions in 5.11

Tags: solaris

I'm trying to adapt some scripts that run under Solaris 5.10 to 5.11. Solaris changed their OS upgrade method, and you no longer install individual patches. The script displays the version numbers so field personnel can make sure that they have the correct OS version.

In 5.10, uname looks like this:

```
> uname -a
SunOS inez 5.10 Generic_138888-07 sun4u sparc SUNW,UltraAX-i2 Solaris
```

Where 138888 is the Cluster Version and 07 is the Jumbo patch version.  Do these versions have any meaning in Solaris 5.11?

```
 > uname -a
SunOS sh-sparc-t6320-bl0 5.11 11.2 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-T6320 Solaris
```

Would 11.2 be considered the "Jumbo version"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running Solaris 11 or later, the Right Thing to Do (tm) is to use the output from 'pkg info' for the packages that you are interested in.

For the use-case you mention, that package would most like be 'core-os'. You can extract various pieces of information from the output:

```
$ pkg info core-os
      Name: system/core-os
   Summary: Core Solaris
Description: Operating system core utilities, daemons, and configuration
            files.
  Category: System/Core
     State: Installed
 Publisher: solaris
   Version: 0.5.11
Build Release: 5.11
    Branch: 0.175.2.0.0.42.2
Packaging Date: Tue Jun 24 18:49:27 2014
      Size: 31.41 MB
      FMRI: pkg://solaris/system/core-os@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.2.0.0.42.2:20140624T184927Z
```

Another important thing to check is the 'entire' incorporation.

At this point it would be very, very useful for you to go and read the information available on oracle.com relating to packaging in the 11, 11.1 and 11.2 releases. I suggest starting at http://www.oracle.com/us/products/servers-storage/solaris/solaris11/resources/index.html and following the links.

Oh, and finally - you ask if "11.2 could be considered the Jumbo Version?" - to which the answer is no, it is not.

Answer (score 2):

in Solaris 11 SRU is about the best equivalent to Cluster/Jumbo Patch.
So you could run:

```
#  pkg info entire | grep Summary
   Summary: entire incorporation including Support Repository Update (Oracle Solaris 11.2.8.4.0).
```

Or to clean it up a bit:

```
# pkg info entire | grep Summary | sed 's/.*[\(]\(.*\)[\)]./\1/' | awk '{print $NF}'
11.2.8.4.0
```

Gerry Haskins of Oracle has a great blog on patching @
https://blogs.oracle.com/patch/[Patch Corner](https://blogs.oracle.com/patch/)